# Iterate over a Matlab table using column headings

Tags: matlab

How can I iterate over the columns of a Matlab table? The Python equivalent and assuming data was a pandas data frame would be:

```
variable_names=data.keys() #get variable names
for i in variable_names:   # iterate over and print all data using variable names
    print data[i]
```

But the corresponding for a Matlab table does not work:

```
f='Vilar_data.xls';
data=readtable(f);
variables=data.Properties.VariableNames; %get variable names
for i=variables,
    data(1:end,{i})                      %attemt to iterate over the data by column headings
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick

```
% generate some random table with 100 rows 
entry  = table(rand(100,1),randi(100,100,1),cellstr(char(randi([65,90],100,5))));
% extract the var names 
var = entry.Properties.VariableNames;
% now for each column display the contents in three different ways 
% obviously you could do whatever you like with the data
for ii=var
    disp(entry.(ii{1})(1:4));% display only the first 4 entries 
    disp(entry.(ii{1})(:)');% display all the entries as a row
    disp(entry.(ii{1})(end-4:end));% display only the last 4 entries 
end
```

Enjoy